# Адаптивный сайт, высота колонок одинаковая, подстраивается под максимальную

Tags: css, html5, адаптивная-верстка

Вопрос в том, чтобы высота всех колонок была одинаковая, и подстраивалась под контент в них. Ширина колонок 25%, для адаптивности. Пробовал высоту через min-height, но при сужении страницы, если контента больше чем min-height, столбец начинает тянутся вниз по высоте, и выглядит некрасиво. Есть ли ещё способ без использования flex-box? Спасибо!
Примечание: у столбцов по периметру должны быть внешние границы, и между границами отступ, это обязательное условие. 
HTML:

```css
 .features {
        margin-top: 20px;
        margin-bottom: 75px;
  }
  .feature-item {
        float: left;
        width: 25%;
        color: #000000;
        padding: 0 6px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

     .feature-item-inner {
        border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;  
    }
```

```html
<div class="features">
       <div class="feature-item ">
              <div class="feature-item-inner">                                            <p class="feature-description">
                        text text text text text text text text 
                     </p>
              </div>
       </div>
       <div class="feature-item ">
              <div class="feature-item-inner">                                            <p class="feature-description">
                        text text text text text text text text
                        text text text text text text text text 
                     </p>
              </div>
       </div>
      <div class="feature-item ">
              <div class="feature-item-inner">                                            <p class="feature-description">
                        text text text text text text text text
                        text text text text text text text text 
                        text text text text text text text text 
                     </p>
              </div>
       </div>
      <div class="feature-item">
              <div class="feature-item-inner">                                            <p class="feature-description">
                        text text text text text text text text
                        text text text text text text text text 
                        text text text text text text text text 
                     </p>
               </div>
       </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/yu02c5tk/

Answer (score 3):

Можно через свойство `display: table-cell;`

```css
.col {
  width: 25%;
  padding: 5px;
  display: table-cell;
   box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
  }
```

```html
<div class="col">text text text text text text text text</div>
<div class="col">text text text text text text text texttext text text text text text text text</div>
<div class="col">text text text text text text text texttext text text text text text text texttext text text text text text text text</div>
<div class="col">text text text text text text text texttext text text text text text text texttext text text text text text text texttext text text text text text text text</div>
```

Comment: Хорошее решение. Жаль только - неадаптивная верстка.

Comment: вот как раз то табличная вёрстка всегда была адаптивная

Comment: а чтобы между границами столбцов были отступы можно при этом способе осуществить?

Comment: конечно , сделать border-right:10px solid transparent; вот пример :http://codepen.io/Geyan/pen/kXdLyw

Comment: к сожалению не подходит. У меня в макете внешние границы у этих столбцов по периметру, и между границами отступ, это обязательное условие. border-right не подойдет

Comment: последний border-right можно убрать - но ваше право